# Need a clue with Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract some information from a string.

This is the string that I receive (JAVA) : 
    `45056 <LIGNE> 164 336 143 191 </LIGNE>`

This is the Regex I use: 
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*)>(.*)</\\1>");`

The output : `LIGNE 164 336 143 191`

I want to have the 5 digits numbers too, i can't figure out how to extract it. I tried with

`(\\d+)<(.*)>(.*)</\\1>`

but, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(\\d+)\\s*<(.*)>(.*)</\\1>` note the `\\s*` after the number group. That should help match any spaces between the number and the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what it is you want but, this should print out the 5 digit number as well:

```
\\d{5}\\s+<([A-Z]+)>([^<]+)</\\1>
```

Comment: You probably want that first number in a match group

Comment: @AndrewWhite Yeah I said I wasn't sure exactly what the OP was trying to do.  That depends entirely on what they're hoping to accomplish.